# how do we store some user input data on a file?

Tags: python

```
oph = open("g_n")

e4 = input("enter your nick name for the game? ")

oph.write(e4)
```

I tried to use this but it says" NOT WRITABLE"

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify that you are opening the file with write permissions

```py
with open("g_n", "w") as file:
    e4 = input("enter you nickname for the game? ")
    file.write(e4)
```